# Не работают события для jquery-file-upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Вряд ли суждено получить ответ (судя по recent вопросам), но все же попытаюсь.

Не работают тупо никакие события, ни завершения загрузки, ни прогресс - ничего. Хотя файл успешно загружается - у меня есть возможность дебажить и сервер, и клиент, так вот на сервер успешно приходит запрос, он отдает ответ... Плагин же полностью все это дело игнорирует. Где я накосячил?

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fileUploadUri = "@Model.FileUploadUri";
    </script>
}

<div>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files">
    <br/>
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Скрипт

```
$(function () {
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        url: getUri($("#fileupload")[0].value),
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log("Done!");
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            console.log(progress);
            //$("#progress .progress-bar").css(
            //    "width",
            //    progress + "%"
            //);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда, короче, вопрос пришлось решать на серверной стороне. Чтобы эвент сработал, нужно возвращать JSON с Content-Type... `text/html` (sic!) ! То есть IE9 понимает ответ только в в этом формате, и нужно указать `json` в `dataType`, а вот на сервере проставлять не `application/json`, а `text/html`.

Такие вот чудеса архаичных браузеров... То, что пришлось ломать пайплайн, чтобы возвращать JSON с отличным от него mime-type отдельная тема...